# Nonzero solutions to the functional ODE $f'(x)=f(f(x))$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Does $\frac{df}{dx}=f(f(x))$ have nonzero solutions? And if so, what analytic/numerical methods can be used to characterize them?

Comment: Problem B5 on the 2010 Putnam was about this ODE. This problem states that there are no solutions that are (i) always positive, and (ii) defined on the entire real line.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819888/a-fierce-differential-delay-equation-df-dx-ffx